# "Je vais tout te montrer" ou "Je vais te tout montrer" ?

Tags: pronoms, compléments

> Je vais *tout te* montrer

OU

> Je vais *te tout* montrer ?

Ce qui me surprend dans cette phrase et l'utilisation de pronom *tout* avant le verbe... je ne suis même pas sûr qu'elle soit grammaticalement correcte: ne doit-on pas dire plutôt

> Je vais te montrer tout

car *tout* ne fait pas partie des pronoms COD, COI et *y*, *en* ?

Comment: Je dirais soit *tout te montrer* ou *te montrer tout* : voir aussi [ma question ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43588/si-nous-voulons-tous-les-sauver) (une syntaxe un peu différent mais le même ordre de mots).

Comment: @LukeSawczak Ta question est aussi interessante, mais un peu différent: dans ta question *tous* modifie le pronom *les*, alors que ici il s'agit de deux pronoms, qui renvoient aux objets différents, comme *je vais **te le** montrer*. (si j'ai bien compris la pgrase, bien sûr.)

Answer (score 3):

Les formes *Je vais tout te montrer* et *Je vais te montrer tout* sont toutes deux utilisées, la deuxième étant plus relâchée.

*Je vais te tout montrer* n'est plus employé ou idiomatique aujourd'hui mais ce type de tournure était possible dans le passé.